# How do you point out that someone made a terrible mistake?

Tags: colleagues

What do you have to say in the most professional way? "Peter, did you write this bit of code? It sends several MSSQL request to the db and you're not batching it. Did you write it? You deployed the code without letting me review when I told you to always get your tickets reviewed." Would this be ok in a group chat?

Comment: By group chat, do you mean sending him a private DM over chat? If yes, I see nothing wrong with that. And you've check the logs I assume, so you know it's him. Or is your goal is to send that message to everyone on your team?

Comment: Also, consider some other possibilities. Maybe he did ask someone else to review the code. Or perhaps, there was a miscommunication about how that rule was supposed to be applied. And not that I'm defending what he did. I just think it's a good idea to avoid coming in too strong.

Answer (score 14):

*Disclaimer*: If you indeed *are* Peters boss, then get them into a private room and ask them what the hell they were thinking, not following your orders. But I guess you are *not* their actual boss, but another developer, just maybe more experienced, more senior or with more knowledge about the company's systems, so this is the version for you:

---

Well, lets start... your sentence is accusatory, calls someone out, repeatedly and has no constructive outcome. So no, it's in no way appropriate of a supportive, collaborative environment. If you run your team like a sweatshop it might be common, otherwise it will be experienced as bad style by all in the channel, not only Peter.

You already drew conclusions ("you deployed the code without letting me review") about the only subject you *don't* know anything about, while you are happily playing dumb about all the things you actually have evidence of ("Did you write it?" => look it up in your source control system).

Then let's go over the wording. For the non-developers here, batching database statements is an optimization. Compare the database to a warehouse worker. You need 100 things from the warehouse and the normal way would be to tell them you need a thing. And when they come back with it, you tell them you need another, on and on until you have your 100 items. "Batching" means you first compile and then give them a *list* of your 100 things to fetch from the start, so they don't need to go back and forth 100 times but just once. That is more effective teh more items you need. Although a database cannot tire or be frustrated, so it's not as bad as it sounds. Batching database statements is a performance optimization. Not doing it will just yield the same correct results, it will just take longer. Maybe a lot longer to the point of the program being unusable for it's purpose. A "terrible mistake" is running over a colleagues kid in the parking lot, sleeping with your bosses wife, leaking business secrets, accidentially setting something of fire or stealing a computer. Not optimizing a program is certainly not the best they could do, but also not a "terrible mistake".

Then let's look at the "I told you so" part. The only viable option to say "I told you so" is in a private chat when you are their boss. Then it is indeed fair to say "why didn't you follow my orders?". Otherwise, they are under no obligation to follow your lead. I wonder why you need to tell them in the first place. Don't you have a document like coding guidelines or a Definition of Done where you wrote down that those kind of statements need to be batched? It's certainly not only them that need to batch their statements, so it should be a guideline written down somewhere so that you don't need to tell everyone who is new.

So it seems, you are just bullying them over an unwritten rule that is rather esoteric. Because you have no evidence that this unwritten rule is even useful. This rule is *situational* and you have provided no hint that the situation even occurs. "Don't use the elevator in case of a fire" doesn't mean you get to bully everyone who uses the elevator all the time. I would want to see *some* indicator that there is fire before I let you lecture me on that.

So let's see if we can turn that into something constructive:

> Hey guys, I just ran the new feature for our largest customer and it takes about 13 minutes. I almost shot down the process, I thought it crashed. That's way too long. Our other features take less then 30 seconds. Peter, I think that you know most about it since you worked on it, maybe you can check and make sure we did not miss something? We should be able to get the performance into the same ballpark as the other features. Also, can we add some acceptance criteria about performance to our requirements in the future? I have a hard time figuring out what would actually be *acceptable* for our customer, plus we would be able to test it more thouroughly before deploying it to production.

This is more neutral. You did not accuse Peter of anything. You made suggestions for improvement. Sure, people in the know can read between the lines and know exactly what went wrong and who did it, but that is on *them*, not on you. You did not point fingers.